# @Scope request and prototype in Spring 3.1.2 with struts2 controllers

Tags: spring, struts2

I am trying to upgrade from Spring 3.0.3 to 3.1.2.

It is a struts2 app, with a controller/action marked as @Scope("request").

A new action object is created on each request. The action bean has a `SearchCriteria` object injected into it. The SearchCriteria class is marked with @Scope("prototype"). So I'd expect a new one to get created on every request, which is how it worked with spring 3.0.3.

But now first time it sees it as a prototype and creates a new one, but from then on it uses a cached version. I've tried to debug it, but am getting no where fast.

Maybe there is a new configuration setting I'm not aware of? Or any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: you using struts2-spring plugin??

Comment: Yes, i am. Turns out I can use Autowired instead of Resource annotation, and it works. Guess injecting by name must have changed in the latest version. Very weird.